# Why does the Chumash wait until Mattos to discuss the laws of Kashering vessels?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kashering-kosherization, mattos

The main place the Chumash discusses laws of Kashering is after the war with Midian. One of the explanations I've seen is that this was the first battle where they captured items from a country which was not part of the future Israel (and one is allowed to eat not-Kosher food during the conquest of Israel).

But what about cooking items taken from the Egypt? And even if you'll answer that the Jews kept kosher in Egypt, (in addition to the meat vessels which became not Kosher after receiving the Torah) what about the looted cooking utensils which we looted from Egypt?

Comment: Maybe they didn't keep kosher at all back then before the Torah was given. That would explain why God didn't discuss the commandments they hadn't been given yet.

Comment: They demonstrably kept kept a form of kosher, as evidenced by Yosef having the calf he served his brothers slaughtered in front of them so as to prove proper technique, but it was clearly not "our" kashrut given that apparently gentiles could schect!

Comment: @JoshK where is that evidence?

Comment: @DoubleAA And if they didn't, they would have to kasher their dishes when the Torah was given (unless they didn't keep Kosher at all throughout the 40 years)

Comment: @shmuel they didn't cook the first day anyway bc of Yom Tov? What about all the other Mitzvot which became relevant right away but aren't recorded in parshat yitro?

Comment: @Double AA Bereshit 46:13, Yosef waits specifically for their arrival so they can see the animal slaughtered in front of them :וַיַּ֨רְא יוֹסֵ֣ף אִתָּם֮ אֶת־בִּנְיָמִין֒ וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ לַֽאֲשֶׁ֣ר עַל־בֵּית֔וֹ הָבֵ֥א אֶת־הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים הַבָּ֑יְתָה וּטְבֹ֤חַ טֶ֙בַח֙ וְהָכֵ֔ן כִּ֥י אִתִּ֛י יֹאכְל֥וּ הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים בַּֽצָּהֳרָֽיִם׃

When Joseph saw Benjamin with them, he said to his house steward, “Take the men into the house; slaughter and prepare an animal, for the men will dine with me at noon.”

Comment: @joshk no Yosef waits for their arrival for no specific reason at all, but probably primarily because of lack of refrigeration. No one cooked anything in advance back then if they could help it. What a waste.

Comment: Rabbeinu Bahya comments: וטבוח טבח. צוה זה למנשה בנו שהרי בני יעקב נזהרים היו על השחיטה.

. וטבוח טבח, “and have meat slaughtered.” Joseph commanded Menashe his eldest son to do the slaughtering seeing that the sons of Yaakov were careful not to eat meat which had not been slaughtered in accordance with Jewish law. @Double AA

Comment: @joshk so your calling a comment by r bahya "demonstrable evidence"? Can you see why that would be unclear to many people? Maybe that Midrash isn't accepted by all, or acceptable as literal at all?

Comment: @Double AA I remembered incorrectly and in my mind had attributed the comment to Rashi, only seeing it was a less unimpeachable source when I looked it up to post. Point taken.

Comment: @shmuel because they didn't have any fire prepared from yesterday? They didn't know the details of what was permitted so they refrained? Once it was the next day it's not ben yomo so no need to kasher. Midian was only for Ben yomo anyway